# Windows - Android Studio No Longer Integrates With Subversion

Tags: android-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, android-studio-2.1

When I first set up Android Studio on Windows, it was working with the TortoiseSVN install I had set up. A while ago I got a message that my Subversion client was out of date. I updated it to 1.8, but it was apparently too new for Android Studio at the time.

Now I'm running Android Studio 2.1.3 and TortoiseSVN 1.9.3, and it seems like they should be compatible. The command line client is set up, and I can see my repository in the "SVN Repositories" view. However, any other interaction with SVN (check out, commit, update) either times out or gives the error: `Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E000002: Can't make directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/filePath/C:\Users\filePath': No such file or directory` .

How do I get it to use the right path, or is there something else I have set up wrong? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio, but that did not seem to help.

Comment: Take a closer look at the path in the error. The problem is with Cygwin. Why is there Cygwin-based path that points to nowhere?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out -- I'm having Android Studio use the the default directory 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Subversion'. Is there another setting where it could be overriding that with the Cygwin path?

Comment: Do not use Cygwin-based svn client. Install native Windows svn.exe client instead. And remove cygwin from %path%

Comment: I thought I had it set to use the SVN client included with Tortoise, but apparently it was weighing the path more heavily than the in-client setting. Removing cygwin from the path fixed it!